# How to reduce unnecessary waiting time when using IBM's backend?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I'm working with a program, which needs iterations of quantum computation like this

```
def quantum(n):
    Grover(oracle).run(QuantumInstance(...))
    #n is input size associated with oracle, 
    #and some other components are omitted.

for n in range(0,10):
    start = time.time()
    quantum(n)
    end = time.time()
```

Now I have to wait for hours to run this on the 16-qubit quantum computer. So is there any way to pack all computation into one round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `quantum()` method creates a circuit, you can run lots of circuits in one go by using the `execute` command. For example `execute([grover_1, grover_2, grover_3], backed=my_backend)`.

Comment: Yes, but can I count time for each computation?

Comment: Yes this is returned as a parameter in the results object :)

Comment: I'm new in using this framework, so sorry, but it seems the algorithm `Grover` in `aqua.algorithms` is not a circuit which can be accepted by `execute` directly, right? Then is there any way to `execute` some simple methods like `Grover`, without touching too much circuit work?

Comment: Instead of doing `grover.run()` you can do `grover.construct_circuit()`. This will return a circuit which can then be run by `execute`

Comment: Update: I have just found results given by the quantum processor contain only an overall `time_taken` for total time, while simulators provider time counted for each circuit. So is there any way to deal with it? (Maybe this is a little off-topic, I posted [another question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12096/how-to-get-running-time-for-each-circuit-executed-on-ibms-quantum-processors-in) for this issue.)